# Cannot open opera dragonfly

Tags: opera, opera-dragonfly

I am trying to debug some code in Opera 12.15, but it makes references to menu and commands that do not appear on my screen. I want to open Opera Dragonfly but cannot figure out how to do it.

Comment: `ctrl+shift+I` should do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of ways to open Opera Dragonfly:

Shortcut:

- Mac: <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>
- Win/Linux: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>

Menu item:

- Mac: Tools → Advanced → Opera Dragonfly
- Win/Linux: Click on the Opera menu in the upper-left-hand corner of the Opera browser interface and select Page → Developer Tools → Opera Dragonfly

Open Dragonfly with the element you want to inspect in focus:

- Right click, select Inspect Element.

For more information - [documentation](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/documentation/).

Comment: Yep, I figured that out later that afternoon, but thanks for posting a correct answer.

Comment: [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[I] also closes it, even if Dragonfly has failed to load, so therefore has no close button.

Comment: ctrl+shift+I opens an inspector but it is not opera dragonfly. Also Dragonfly is ot listed under  Developer Tools → Opera Dragonfly . Any ideas why this might be ?

Comment: Opera Dragonfly was never ported when Opera switched to Blink in Opera 15. It was originally the plan, but it never happened.